# Where error in add FOREIGN KEY in phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting up foreign keys in phpMyAdmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459312/setting-up-foreign-keys-in-phpmyadmin)

```
ALTER table podcategory add FOREIGN KEY (category_id) 
           REFERENCES category(category_id)
ON UPDATE RESTRICT
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

When i send script in phpmyadmin i get error

```
Can't create table './C292729_T25027/#sql-be0_30ed238.frm' (errno: 150)
```

How to add this FOREIGN KEY?

Comment: make sure your db engine is `InnoDB` and reference column is `indexed` column. check this answer [setup foreign key](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6244893/1225337)

Comment: table have indexes and InnoDb

Answer (score 0):

try this type:

```
ALTER TABLE `aaaa` ADD CONSTRAINT fk_comp_id FOREIGN KEY ( `comp_id` ) REFERENCES `comps` ( `id` );
```

Or this SO answer/question might be able to help you out for sure:
[Setting up foreign keys in phpMyAdmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459312/setting-up-foreign-keys-in-phpmyadmin)

Comment: an example, you can replace it by your own index as you like.

Comment: #1005 - Can't create table './C292729_T25027/#sql-be0_30ee499.frm'

Comment: here `fk_comp_id` is the name of the `index`,

Comment: @strannik for the 1005 error, check out this item: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937490/mysql-error-1005-cant-create-table-errno-150-when-i-try-create-more-tha